# bot sending message information instead of message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i am currently making a chat channel, where you can chat in the channel and the bot sends into an another server that has the channel named **chat-chan**,

here is my code:

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.name == 'chat-chan' and message.author.bot == False:
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.name}:  {message}")
```

instead it sends the information of the message instead of the message itself

**Mini:  <Message id=12345678910 channel= type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=12345678910 name='Mini' discriminator='4140' bot=False nick=None guild=> flags=>**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the object of the message. To access message itself you need to replace it with `message.content`

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.name == 'chat-chan' and message.author.bot == False:
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.name}:  {message.content}")
```